# SSIS Merge Transformation sorting for multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sorting, merge, ssis, etl

I have read the various documents on the `Merge Transformation` and they all say the data has to be sorted, but none of them talk about which columns and how to decide what columns to sort. If, for example, my merge join criteria is on multiple columns then do all of them need to be sorted?

My production data has 3+ millions of rows and the merge works but I cannot validate if it is accurate to determine if I need to sort on more columns. I tried to create test/dummy data but the output is as expected be it if I do one sort or multiple so I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

Comment: You need to sort it so both datasets are sorted the same way. This means you must use the same "key" to sort on. If that is 1 or 2 or more is up to how your data looks like.

Comment: You can read more here https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-merge-join-transformation/

Comment: Thank you @plaidDK. I had seen that article also but it didn't talk about which columns, just that the data had to be sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a merge join, you have to sort all columns that will be used to join both tables, and the sort must be in the same order.

Example: if you have two tables:

- Table1 (Name,Age,Address)
- Table2 (FullName,Age,Contact)

You need to join on `Name = Fullname AND Age = Age`, SO you have to sort both columns in both tables and each two related columns must have the same order:

- Table1: Name (order 1), Age (order 2) *(similar to `ORDER BY Name,Age`)*
- Table2: Fullname (order 1), Age (order 2) *(similar to `ORDER BY FullName,Age`)*

*@PlaidDK has provided a very useful [link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-merge-join-transformation/) in the comments, you can get  more details in it*

---

*Side Note: you can sort columns using the `SORT` component or if using an OLEDB command as source, you can use the `ORDER BY` clause in the command and mark columns as sorted (in the advanced editor)*

Comment: Awesome. This helps me a lot. Thank you!